# orientdb get intersection of two egdes result

Tags: sql, orientdb

I can make result individually below.
1.   traverse out_e_Direct from #29:1042 while $depth < 2 --> Movie title taken by the director
2.   traverse out_e_Played from #29:5535 while $depth < 2 --> Moive title played by the actor

I hope to find the common edges from them. (intersection)
but I don't know how to make query about these edges relationship.

Could you help me?

Comment: Have you seen OrientDB's Intersect Function?
http://orientdb.com/docs/last/SQL-Functions.html#intersect

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
select expand($c)
let $a=(traverse out_e_Direct from #29:1042 while $depth < 2),
$b=(traverse out_e_Played from #29:5535 while $depth < 2),
$c=intersect($a,$b)
```

Regards,
Michela